# JUNG - fit to page for large graphs (~1000 nodes)

Tags: java, graph, jung

I want to migrate to JUNG for displaying network elements as a graph.
The problem is that I have around 1000 nodes and when the view is opened I want to display all of them in a single page without manually zooming out.
The icon size of the node is (60, 50). 
If I set the visualization viewer size to a smaller value(let's say (1000, 1000)), then all the nodes will be overlapping because the icon is not re-sized.

Does JUNG directly supports the fit-to-page feature? If not, how can I obtain this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

JUNG supports two kinds of zooming modes: layout-based (in which the elements remain the same size, but may be moved closer together or farther apart), and view-based (in which the element size changes as you zoom out and in).

These two modes are demonstrated in PluggableRendererDemo.  (It also demonstrates a hybrid mode, which you may find useful.)